# Selenium css and xpath selector

Tags: vba, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

I am trying to select an element using CSS selector (and have tried XPath also).

```
<div data-sheetstartpoint="1">
    <div class="booking">
        <div class="startsheet two">
            <div class="title">
                <div class="time">Time</div>
                <div class="cols">
                    <div class="hidden-xs two">Team 1</div>
                    <div class="hidden-xs two">Team 2</div>
                    <div class="visible-xs two">Teams</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="slot" data-startpointno="1">
                <div class="time" id="timelabel"> 07:30 </div>
                <div class="cols">
                    <div class="timeslot  " data-roundteamid="" data-slotno="1" data-time="17/04/2021 06:30:00" data-startpointno="1" data-offset="0" data-bookingname="">
                        <span class="available-to-book">Available </span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="timeslot  " data-roundteamid="" data-slotno="2" data-time="17/04/2021 06:30:00" data-startpointno="1" data-offset="0" data-bookingname="">
                        <span class="available-to-book">Available </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

I have made a CSS selector (and have also looked using Chropath)
I am getting an element not found error.
The selectors I am using

```
FindElementByCss(".timeslot[data-slotno*='1'][data-time*='17/04/2021 06:30:00']")

FindElementByXPath("//*[@id='hdidbookingcontent']/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]")
```

I see further up the page there is a class "container" - is this something that would impact selection?

Comment: Have you looked to see if they are in an IFRAME?

Comment: Your CSS selector works fine but you don't need the * before = on either of them. `*=` means contains but neither need it because they equal those values. We can't check the XPath because you didn't include that relevant HTML for the ID and down. I would not suggest that XPath given the number of levels and most with just indices. That's going to break very easily with minor page changes.

Comment: Hi   I am not sure if they are in an I frame   not something I know anything about   . I will try to find out . Ok re the * I think perhaps earlier I had the data time only as 17.  Glad to hear I have the actual css selectors pretty much right (even if they are not yet fi d g what I want!)   Thanky you got help

Comment: Hi  As far as I can see there is no iframe involved. I have modified the CSS selectors as suggested but still get "No such ElementError".

Comment: You should try to verify your locators in the browser. Using Chrome dev tools, you can use `$$()` for CSS selectors and `$x()` for XPath, e.g. `$$(".timeslot[data-slotno*='1'][data-time*='17/04/2021 06:30:00']")`. See if it returns at least one element. We can't really help past that without a link to the page.

Comment: Hi  I have tried in console and it finds the element (so progress thanks to you)   I was also trying to list all the elements and came up with elements that did not look like they were on the page. So I am wondering if my CSS selector is looking at the page that is displayed on screen. When I open the site manually it opens the page in a new tab. I was exploring the getWindowHandle( ): and switch window options but not sure so easy in VBA Selenium. I will try to see if I can ensure CSS is looking at correct page.

Comment: Any help to do this much appreciated (as is the assistance so far) As a new user I am not sure of correct way to show on here that you have helped/answered

Comment: Your `FindElement*` calls are going to return the first element found. So, if there are 5 elements that match and the one you want is not the first, that may be the issue. Can you share a link to the page?

Comment: Hi  Unfortunately this is a members page which I think I am unable to share. When opening using selenium there is no new tab showing in browser. When opening manually there is a new tab. I have used .switch to next window and my CSS selectors are now working. Thank you for explaining CSS selectors (I have hopefully grasped) and also demonstrating use in console.  On to the next stage and thanks once again for your time and assistance